# Error: Can't bind to 'rightIcon' since it isn't a known property of 'accordion-list'

Tags: ionic3, angular5

I get an error

> "Error: Can't bind to 'rightIcon' since it isn't a known property of
>   'accordion-list'.

I want to use like below in my html. please help how to do it

```
<accordion-list [title]="'details'" textColor="#FFF" hasMargin="false" headerColor="#1CA0D7"  [rightIcon]="'bus'">
        <ion-list id="new-data" ngModelGroup="newData" #orderData="ngModelGroup">
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label class="formLabel">Name</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text"  name="customerName" id="customerName" ngModel required #customerName="ngModel" class="formInput" text-right></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </accordion-list>
```

Please help me know how to do it

> ionic -version
>
> ```
>  _             _
> (_) ___  _ __ (_) ___
> | |/ _ \| '_ \| |/ __|
> | | (_) | | | | | (__
> |_|\___/|_| |_|_|\___|  CLI 4.1.2
> ```
>
> ==========================
>
> ng -v
>     ionic -v
>
> Angular CLI: 6.2.4
>     Node: 8.11.1
>     OS: linux x64
>     Angular: 
>     ...
>
> Package                      Version
>
> ---
>
> @angular-devkit/architect    0.8.4
>       @angular-devkit/core         0.8.4
>       @angular-devkit/schematics   0.8.4
>       @schematics/angular          0.8.4
>       @schematics/update           0.8.4
>       rxjs                         6.2.2
>       typescript                   2.9.2
>
> =========================================="

Comment: Can you share accordion list component source? This is not a standard ionic component so please share implementation you have in your case if you need help

Comment: Thanks i got the issue and solved. Missed to add the custom components in the component.module.ts file